# java's getByte() equivalent in python

Tags: java, python, string, arrays, data-conversion

I am a nebie to python. I have a java method which accepts a string, converts the string to a byte array and returns the byte array. The method looks like this.

```
private static byte[] convert(String str) {
        byte[] byteArray = str.getBytes();
        return byteArray;
    }
```

`convert("sr_shah")` results in a byte array like this 
`115 114 95 115 104 97 104`. On using `Charset.defaultCharset()` i came to know that my machine's dfault charectorset is `windows-1252`.

Now i need to create exact equivalent of the above method in Python. The problem i am facing now is with  converting string to bytearray. I am unable to get java's getBytes() equivalent in python. I searched in internet and took many help from stackoverflow's previous posts on converting string to byte array but unfortunately none of them worked for me.

The methods i used are `bytearray(),bytes(),str.encode()`. I used encodings like
 `windows-1252,utf_16,utf_8,utf_16_le,utf_16_be,iso-8859-1` unfortunately none of them give the right result as i expected(i.e like the byte array i got from java getBytes()) . I am not getting what wrong thing am i doing. this is how i tried in python.

```
>>> bytearray('sr_shah','windows-1252')
bytearray(b'sr_shah')
>>> bytearray('sr_shah','utf_8')
bytearray(b'sr_shah')
>>> bytearray('sr_ahah','utf_16')
bytearray(b'sr_ahah')
>>> bytearray('sr_shah','utf_16_le')
bytearray(b'sr_shah')
>>> name = 'sr_shah'
>>> name.encode('windows-1252')
'sr_shah'
>>> name.encode('utf_8')
'sr_shah'
>>> name.encode('latin_1')
'sr_shah'
>>> name.encode('iso-8859-1')
'sr_shah'
>>> name.encode('utf-8')
'sr_shah'
>>> name.encode('utf-16')
'\xff\xfes\x00r\x00_\x00s\x00h\x00a\x00h\x00'
>>> name.encode('utf-16-le')
's\x00r\x00_\x00s\x00h\x00a\x00h\x00'
>>>
```

Please help me to get the right conversion.

Comment: `[B@1ce59895` isn't the encoded string. It rather looks like a representation of the *address*  of the encoded string.

Comment: The problem is that you are not looking at byte arrays but only at their string representations. Java’s `byte[].toString()` implementation returns the not very meaningful `"[B@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())` representation and it’s not clear why you want to reproduce *that* output. It looks like python produces a string representation showing the contents of the byte array in a manner that is identical to the original string for `ASCII` based characters and encodings. If you want to compare the array’s byte values you have to print each byte as number (in both languages).

Comment: Are you sure `[B@1ce59895` doesn't refer to an address? I think it means a byte array at address `0x1ce59895`.

Comment: sorry i just posted the adress only. now i just edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bytearray` you have created in Python contains the bytes you want. To see their decimal representation, print the bytes one by one:

```
>>> for x in bytearray('sr_shah','windows-1252'): print(x)
...
115
114
95
115
104
97
104
```

Comment: I dont understand, why the output of `System.out.println(secret.getBytes());` and `for x in bytearray(secret,'windows-1252'): print(x)` is different, secret='secret'.. Can someone help me in understanding

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
str = 'sr_shah'
b = [ord(s) for s in str]
print b

**Output**

[115, 114, 95, 115, 104, 97, 104]
```

the [ord() built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) is as close as I know to the getByte() function you want, although it works on single characters, so you need to deal with the arrays yourself.